# Wrong artifact being taken during runtime

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, war

Let me format the question a little bit :)

**The problem is**

In the runtime the specific value of enum cannot be resolved (it was introduced in 1.2 version of dependency included in project's pom.xml - this version of the library is called common-1.2.jar)

**Probably caused by**

Wrong dependency being taken during runtime.

**Description:**

In the WEB-INF/lib directory of generated war file there are three versions of common library (common-1.2.jar, common-1.1.jar, common-1.0.jar) and it looks that during runtime the older one is used. I checked it by calling values() method on my enum: there is no new - added in the 1.2 version - value there.

I executed mvn dependency:tree and there is only one common library there - common-1.2.jar. But - what can be observer - the wrong one is being used.

**Question**

Is there a way to find out what causes the project to use the older version during runtime?

Comment: How do you deploy your war, maybe you are overwriting and that's the issue.

Comment: I use the `mvn package` command. That's what you are asking for?

Comment: After `mvn package`, you have a `war`, what do you do with it?

Comment: @RC. I run it on the server with the java command: `java -XX:PermSize=512 -XX:MaxPermSize=512 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dconfig=/my/conf/file.properties -jar /my/project/file.war`

Answer (score 0):

use eclipse EE +maven plugin to trace the dependency

In eclipse EE, it has installed maven plugin. So just click the pom.xml, in editor window bottom, choose "Dependency Hierarchy". In the right side, choose commons-1.1.jar or commons-1.0.jar, in the left side "Dependency Hierarchy", you will see which jar imported the old jar.

In pom.xml, find the artifact, and add
`<excludes><exclude><artifactId>commons</artifactId><version>1.0 or 1.1</version></exclude></excludes>` .

Make sure in the right side, it should not exist any commons-1.0.jar or commons-1.1.jar. So your issue will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The mentioned view is also available in _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_, but it looks that there is only commons-1.2.jar on the right side. I am confused right now.